# Radiance to reflectance error ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator, error-000539, reflectance

[image]

I have been trying and failing for some time to convert the radiance to refectance by following step 4 in [this tutorial](http://ibis.colostate.edu/WebContent/WS/ColoradoView/TutorialsDownloads/CO_RS_Tutorial10.pdf)
I have tried everything I can think of but my knowledge is limited. Would anybody be kind enough to please point out how I can fix/avoid the error messages shown in the image here...

I have copied the messages too:

```
Executing: RasterCalculator rastercalc3_b1_ref=(3.141592654*["rastercalc3_b1"]*Square(1.00679))/(1997.0*Sin(47.40016008*3.141592654/180.0)) \\fsr-srv-06.qm.ds.qmul.ac.uk\Share\RedirectedFolders\fa14012\Desktop\PES\1_data\arc\b1_ref
Start Time: Fri Nov 04 19:58:25 2016
rastercalc3_b1_ref=(3.141592654*[Raster(r"rastercalc3_b1")]*Square(1.00679))/(1997.0*Sin(47.40016008*3.141592654/180.0))
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in rcexec
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).
Failed at Fri Nov 04 19:58:28 2016 (Elapsed Time: 2.38 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the square brackets [] from your expression. The tutorial uses an old version of ArcGIS that has slightly different raster calculator syntax.

Comment: Yes that is right and if you have ENVI , it does a really good job of doing that .